# innerHTML puts in quotations marks, making it to where my <td> row does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, html

```
cell.innerHTML = `style="border: 1px solid #fcfcfc;
            margin-left: 30px;"><span class="nothing"></span>`
```

this innerHTML attribute is supposed to put in this HTML into my td row in my table.

however, this is not working because when i run it the HTML puts quotation marks around "style" causing it to not work correctly.

```
<td>
"style="border: 1px solid #fcfcfc;
            margin-left: 30px;">"
</td>
```

as you can see the extra " is causing this all to throw off and not work correctly. This is the desired output

```
<td style="border: 1px solid #fcfcfc;
        margin-left: 30px;"></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

`innerHTML` changes the whole HTML contained within the element

Here you want to set style of the element, also want to change the HTML content within it. So do these as separated task

```
cell.setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid #fcfcfc; margin-left: 30px;")
cell.innerHTML = "<span class="nothing"></span>"
```

Comment: thank you so much, idk if i couldve figured this out on my own lol